# Comparing adjacent elements together without using zip method

Tags: python

How would you go about comparing two adjacent elements in a list in python? How would save or store the value of that item while going through a for loop? I'm trying not to use the zip method and just using an ordinary for loop.

```
comparing_two_elements = ['Hi','Hello','Goodbye','Does it really work   finding longest length of string','Jet','Yes it really does work']

longer_string = ''


for i in range(len(comparing_two_elements)-1):
    if len(prior_string) < len(comparing_two_elements[i + 1]):
        longer_string = comparing_two_elements[i+1]
print(longer_string)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the `zip()` function? The built-ins are built in for good reason.

Comment: Oh because i noticed C used a temp variable to compare two string together and I was wondering how to do it in python? Oh ignore the prior string I meant to put comparing_two_elements[i].

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do? It sort of looks like you want to find the maximum length string in `comparing_two_elements`.

Comment: If you "save or store the value of that item" in a variable like `longer_string` "while going through a for loop", you had better do something with it in the body of the loop, otherwise it will just be overwritten on the next pass through the loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This doesn't look like you're comparing adjacent elements, it looks like you're trying to find the longest string overall. That's actually pretty easy/efficient, no explicit loops at all: `longest_string = max(name_of_list, key=len)`

Answer (score 0):

The below works simply by 'saving' the first element of your list as the longest element, as it will be the first time you loop over your list, and then on subsequent iterations it will compare the length of that item to the length of the next item in the list.

```
longest_element = None
for element in comparing_two_elements:
    if not longest_element:
        longest_element = element
        continue
    if len(longest_element) < len(element):
        longest_element = element
```

If you want to go the "interesting" route, you could do it with combination of other functions, for eg

```
length_map = map(len, comparing_two_elements)
longest_index = length_map.index(max(length_map))
longest_element = comparing_two_elements[longest_index]
```

Comment: A) The right way to find the longest string would not be this. B) If you initialized `longest_element` as `''`, you could get rid of the first `if`. C) Your "interesting" route is so unPythonic it hurts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the third, optional `step` argument to `range` - and don't subtract `1` from len(...) ! Your logic is incomplete: what if the first of a pair of strings is longer? you don't do anything in that case.

It's not clear what you're trying to do. This `for` loop runs through `i` = 0, 2, 4, ... up to but excluding `len(comparing_two_elements)` (assumed to be even!), and prints the longer of each adjacent pair:

```
for i in range(0, len(comparing_two_elements), 2):
    if len(comparing_two_elements[i]) < len(comparing_two_elements[i + 1]):
        idx = i
    else:
        idx = i + 1
    print(comparing_two_elements[idx])
```

This may not do exactly what you want, but as several people have observed, it's unclear just what that is. At least it's something you can reason about and adapt.

If you just want the longest string in a sequence `seq`, the whole adjacent pairs rigamarole is pointless; simply use:

```
longest_string = max(seq, key=len)
```

Comment: If you don't know what the question is, please ask for clarification in a comment instead of in an answer.